# Cython iterator error

Tags: c++, vector, cython

I use iterator of vector.

An error is produced when compiling:

`Cannot assign type 'iterator' to 'size_t'`.

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def rotate_list(list ll):
    cdef vector[int] vect1 = ll     
    cdef size_t t=0

    t = vect1.end() - vect1.begin()
    return t
```

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, but when I try to construct a simple C++ example with toy classes instead of vectors and iterators I can't get the same error. I think this is an obscure Cython bug and you should report it to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues. (I can't see an obvious workround)

Comment: You can minimize your illustrative example though - It's basically just `end - vect3.begin()` and the appropriate `cdef`s. The bug has nothing to do with `set_intersection`

Comment: Well, an `iterator` isn't a `size_t`... They're fundamentally different types.

Comment: @TriskalJM How to write an analog of a function in example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/ on Cython?

Comment: @TriskalJM but you should be able to subtract two `vector.iterators` from each other to get an integer(and Cython does expose the operator but for some reason it doesn't work)

Comment: By my reading [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd), the subtraction operator for `vector.iterator` returns a `difference_type`, not a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

It works with cython version 0.26.